# Pair Programming on multiple computers

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, multiple-computers, shared-access

At work, we are trying to set up pair programming stations.  For this, we need to have both programmers working from different monitors (with their own keyboard and mouse) on the same file.  Are there any solutions to this problem out there?  Similar to how googledocs works, but for the entire screen, not just the document.

Comment: What's wrong with just using the standard content versioning tools such as Git or SVN that are able to merge in changes to the same file from multiple authors? As long as those authors do not change the same lines then they should be fine, and even then conflicts can easily be resolved.

Comment: Valid question should rather be what's wrong with simply connecting two monitors in mirror mode, two keyboards and two mouses to - surprise - a single desktop computer?
Simpler the better, I'm just writing from this kind of pairing station at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

One particular commercial solution is [TeamPlayer](https://dicolab.com/products/teamplayer/):

> **Multi-user collaboration tool**
>
> Software that enables multiple users working in the same digital
>   environment. All participants can synchronously interact and control
>   applications and content running there.
>
> With TeamPlayer3 multiple users will be synchronously present on
>   screen, each as an unique cursor.
>
> Even use your personal device to join in a session!
>
> **How can I use it?**
>
> Use any application or any content you are accustomed to with multiple
>   users together. All participants are now able to interact and you can
>   collaborate in any task at hand.
>
> Use mice, keyboards, touch screens, tablets, iPads or smartphones as
>   your control device. Whether locally present or remote connecting from
>   any location.
>
> Unique multi-user software for people-centered collaboration. Extend a
>   desktop to a multi-user session.

[image: 1]